# how do i generate sequence numbers in the for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, numbers, sequence, series

i need help to generate a sequence numbers in the `for loop` i have code but it is not working properly as i want to do it is not generating series numbers?

**i want script generate number like this**

```
00500,00501,00502,00503,....so on
```

**here my code**

```
$new_val=500;   
for($i=1;$i<=$new_val;$i++){
if( strlen($i)==1 )
{
$say='0000'.$i;
}
elseif( strlen($i)==2 )
{
$say='000'.$i;
}
elseif( strlen($i)==3 )
{
$say='00'.$i;
}
elseif( strlen($i)==4 )
{
$say='0'.$i;
}
elseif( strlen($i)==5 )
{
$say=$i;
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) is the function, you are looking for (and the sequence could be a simple `for`, or a `while` with `$i++` within).

**Edit**: example:

```
for ($i = 500; haveIFinishedYet(); $i++) {
  $formatted = str_pad($i, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: pozs can you give example please?